Making transformations between ellipsoids using PyPROJ
I am transforming coordinates between the Ellipsoids WGS84 and Hayford International using the code
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

Define CRS objects for WGS84 and Hayford International
wgs84_crs = CRS.from_user_input("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
hayford_crs = CRS.from_user_input("+proj=longlat +ellps=intl")

Create a transformer object
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(wgs84_crs, hayford_crs, always_xy=True)

Define the WGS84 coordinates (longitude, latitude)
wgs84_lon, wgs84_lat = -77.0369, 38.9072

Perform the transformation
hayford_lon, hayford_lat = transformer.transform(wgs84_lon, wgs84_lat)

The final result
print("Hayford International coordinates (longitude, latitude):", hayford_lon, hayford_lat)

Hayford International coordinates (longitude, latitude): -77.0369 38.9072

The result is a change of zero between ellipsoid coordinates. The change is zero again with several random coordinates.
How do I  make this transformation?
